# Laptop brightness change with screen color

Tags: drivers, nvidia, power-management, brightness, automatic

I recently installed an Ubuntu 18 on a DELL laptop with an NVIDIA graphic card. I selected during the install process, the installation of proprietary software.
Since the installation, it seems that when I am running on battery the brightness of the screen is changing constantly depending on the amount of white there is displayed on the screen.
That does not happen when I am plugged-in.
Back in the days I had the same issue on windows with an AMD graphic card, it was a "power saving" feature. But I can't find any information about this on NVIDIA under Linux.
Does anyone know how to disable it once and for all?